# Group key/value pairs in python dictionary by value, maintaining original key associations

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

Looking for an efficient approach to grouping values from a dictionary by their likeness, resulting in an inverted dictionary with the original keys grouped as a list.  I can think of klugy ways to do this, but am interested in other approaches.

Suppose I have the dictionary that looks like the following:

```
{'d1': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
 'd2': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
 'd3': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}}
```

And my desired dictionary, might look like this:

```
{'group1': {'dict': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42}, 'keys': ['d1', 'd2']},
 'group2': {'dict': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}, 'keys': ['d3']}}
```

The important detail is that the original keys, `d1` and `d2`, have been grouped under an arbitrarily named `group1`, grouped by their identical dictionaries from the original dictionary.  Maintaining the original keys -- `d1` and `d2` stored in `keys` list -- is critical as well, and what dictionary they were associated with.  `d3` is alone, because its dictionary is unique.

My bigger goal is to take a dictionary of dictionary that contain parameters for other purposes, but group them where the parameters are identical, such that I can be more efficient and run them together.

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
d = {'d1': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
     'd2': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
     'd3': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}}
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
l = [{'dict': k, 'keys': list(map(itemgetter(0), g))} for k, g in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1].items()), itemgetter(1))]
```

so that `l` would become:

`[{'dict': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42}, 'keys': ['d1', 'd2']}, {'dict': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}, 'keys': ['d3']}]`

Comment: Can I ask you something?

Comment: This is a place to ask questions, isn't it?

Comment: if we go this route and use setdefault `l = ['group1', 'group2']
d1 = {}

for i in l:
    groups = d1.setdefault(i, {})
    inner = groups.setdefault('dict',{})
    morein = groups.setdefault('keys',[])`

Comment: what ist the next step? I can produce the empties but how to fill them?

Comment: I don't think you should pre-make the dict keys `group1` and `group2` because they are a result of the number of groupings found while iterating through the items in the main dict, which you can't know beforehand. Other than that, it's just a matter of keeping track of the last sub-dict and, if the current sub-dict is the same, keep appending the key to the current key list, or if it's different, initialize a new entry with the current key and item.

Comment: Thank you I like your method I can apply this in many other places going to use it

Comment: This approach will work well for my purposes.  @jpp 's is nice as well, but this was a bit easier for me in this situation to modify.  And, does not rely on 3rd party, even though I had access to pandas already.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible but tedious with regular Python. If you are willing to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas to perform a `GroupBy` aggregation:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'d1': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
     'd2': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
     'd3': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index().groupby('goober')\
                    .agg(lambda x: set(x)).reset_index()

print(df)

#   goober     index horse
# 0  False      {d3}  {71}
# 1   True  {d1, d2}  {42}

res = [{'dict': {'goober': row.goober, 'horse': next(iter(row.horse))},
        'keys': list(row.index)} for row in df.itertuples(index=False)]
```

Result:

```
[{'dict': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}, 'keys': ['d3']},
 {'dict': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42}, 'keys': ['d1', 'd2']}]
```

Note I haven't applied any logic to derive `'group1'` and `'group2'` outer dictionary keys. It's not clear *how* these are derived. If they are arbitrary identifiers, you can use `enumerate` in a subsequent step:

```
res2 = {f'group{idx}': d for idx, d in enumerate(res, 1)}
```

Result:

```
{'group1': {'dict': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}, 'keys': ['d3']},
 'group2': {'dict': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42}, 'keys': ['d1', 'd2']}}
```

Comment: `group1` and `group2` are arbitrary, so yes, enumerating would be fine.  And, I am using pandas in other areas, so the requirement is not a problem.  Thanks for this!

Comment: I have a quesiton, can you help?

Comment: If it's clarification on my answer here, sure, that's what comments are for. If it's a new question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it

```
dicts = {
'd1': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42}, 
'd2': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42},
'd3': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}
}

desired_dict = {}
group_num = 0

for d in dicts:
    for dd in desired_dict: # check if the dict exists in out desired_dict
        if desired_dict[dd]['dict'] == dicts[d]: # if yes, just update the keys
            desired_dict[dd].get('keys', []).append(d)
            break
    else:
        group_num += 1 # else make a new dictionary group
        group_name = 'group{0}'.format(group_num)
        desired_dict[group_name] = {'dict': dicts[d], 'keys': [d, ]}

print(desired_dict)


Out: {'group1': {'dict': {'goober': True, 'horse': 42}, 'keys': ['d1', 'd2']}, 
      'group2': {'dict': {'goober': False, 'horse': 71}, 'keys': ['d3']}}
```

Comment: This is where I was headed myself!  But I'm glad to see these other approaches as well.  I hadn't yet made the leap that a list as a final result is equally as good, if not more so.  But your answer is true to the question, so kudos there.